# How do I sort data in Apache Arrow

Tags: apache-arrow

I can't seen to find any examples of sorting data with apache arrow. The closed I have found is [this](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/examples/plasma/sorting/sort_df.py) which sorts the data in userspace.

More specifically I'm interested in the JS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the rust implementation are getting a [sort](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/6306) implementation.